# Core data migration with custom NSEntityMigrationPolicy - efficiency?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, performance, core-data-migration

My iPhone app's core data model is changing and I have a custom mapping model and an NSEntityMigrationPolicy for one of my objects. However, I am worried that some of my users will have thousands of objects in their core data base, are there any best practices for either making the migration as efficient as possible, or conveying to the user what's going on when they load the new update which will try to migrate their data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to warn the user that the app needs to update the data store and you should probably provide a "working" dialog so it doesn't look like the app has hung.

However, the migration is very efficient because it's really just changing the mapping on the store. It doesn't have to actual instantiate all the existing managed objects, it just changes the field names in the store. That can get complex itself in rare cases but most of the time it's barely noticeable.

Comment: What is the best way to warn the user while the splash screen is loading?

Comment: You can't actually change a real "splash screen" which the Apple API calls an initial image. That is loaded automatically by the system before the apps custom code is run. Instead, you just need to popup an alert view over the first operational view informing the user that an data update is taking place.

Comment: If you are trying to migrate data while the splash screen is showing beware!  Your app only has a few seconds to return from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and then your app will be terminated by the OS.